# Even columns in a Bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make my Bootstrap columns the equal size and have been failing.  Using CSS or JavaScript, how can I accomplish this?

[image: Example]

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/UXoKGvHwfJ)

CSS:

```
#grid-selector .container {
    max-width: 400px;
}

#grid-selector [class*="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="grid-selector">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Section 1<br>Space</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Section 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Section 3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Section 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Section 5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Section 6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Section 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row man">
          <div class="col-xs-12">Section 8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row man">
          <div class="col-xs-12">Section 9</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Section 10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">Section 11</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only way to make a div have the same height as other is really through javascript... there are plenty of plugin for this... I tend to use: http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc

Comment: Will try this out, thanks!  I'm trying to make a grid selection tool for a site builder, but users are complaining about the uneven heights confusing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tadaaa! Super [**FLEX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to the rescue!

```
#grid-selector .container {
}
#grid-selector .row {
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch !important;
}
#grid-selector [class*="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

And I even made your example fully responsive instead of fixed width, just because I can ;) .

No, really, I did it to show you it could easily be responsive, but if you want it to be fixed , just add all this code inside a container div (do **NOT** limit the container width as you did!)

see to understand it visually http://www.bootply.com/Wypyz5PaSN and play around

and read more about **[FLEX MODEL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)** at Mozilla MDN

> **The CSS3 Flexible Box, or flexbox,** is a layout mode providing for the arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements
>   behave predictably when the page layout must accommodate different
>   screen sizes and different display devices. For many applications, the
>   flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model in
>   that **it does not use floats**, nor do the flex container's margins
>   collapse with the margins of its contents.
>
> **Many designers will find the flexbox model easier to use**. Child elements in a flexbox can be laid out in any direction and can have
>   flexible dimensions to adapt to the display space. **Positioning child
>   elements is thus much easier**, and complex layouts can be achieved more
>   simply and with cleaner code, as the display order of the elements is
>   independent of their order in the source code. This independence
>   intentionally affects only the visual rendering, leaving speech order
>   and navigation based on the source order.

Comment: `align-items: stretch` and `min-height:100%;` are redundant here. Besides you have linked to `flex` property which is not used here at all.

Comment: in Firefox you need to define both, try it and see by yourself

Comment: The initial value of `align-items` is `stretch`. If Firefox doesn't respect, file a bug.

Comment: Here's [a screenshot](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/4c3a7dce7701cf6c8f5bb028b1ded5d9) of [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/biUZDw96YT) on FireFox 31 which works perfectly.

Comment: Just needed to add a space between #grid-selector and [class*="col-"] and everything just worked great!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create an additional CSS class which is shared between the columns in each row.

In this class, you'd want to define a min-height.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 row1">Section 1<br>Space</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 row1">Section 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would then define your CSS as follows

```
.row1{
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

The reason you'd want to be using min-height as opposed to height, is to retain the responsiveness when you reduce the size of the window. If you were to then do only height, as opposed to min height, as soon as the site becomes smaller, the objects cannot fit inside the div, and don't perform properly.

Comment: `min-height` is not supported in [some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

Comment: `min-height` is not supported in IE7 as well! And plenty of companies still using that "crap"